# MVC AddActionListener doesn't work

Tags: java, model-view-controller, actionlistener, frame

As said on the title, I've a problem on a procject where it's imposed to us to use MVC pattern to realize the game "Colt Express". It's too late to return it again, but I don't understand where is the problem on my code

To give you an idea of the game, there are wagons on each one there is a roof. There are gangsters who can move shoot or hold up treasures which are on wagons and roofs. There's also a sort of Sheriff who moves and shot everytime he sees a gangster (if on the same wagon or roof, same position)

The process of action is particular, there is 2 phases, on the first one, the first gangster chooses a fixed number of action by clicking on associated button, then the second one etc
Here come the seconde phase, first action of the first gangster is done when Action button is clicked, then second gangster's one after another click, as you can see one after the other and only one action happen for each action button click. After that same is done for other action

When I click, nothing happen, i puted a "System.out.println("nothing work") but it doesn't print anything on a click. With setActionCommand() I associated a String to each button on the method AddActionListener(ActionListener aclick)
and instanciated on the class Controleur and created as needed a method actionPerformed(ActionListener aclick) that does something depending on the string that we get on a click by using getActionCommand

Here a classes concerned by my problem :

```
public class VueBoutons extends JPanel {

Direction dir;

JButton Action = new JButton("Action !");
JButton Avance = new JButton("Avancer");
JButton Recule = new JButton("Reculer");
JButton Monte = new JButton("Monter");
JButton Descend = new JButton("Descendre");
JButton Braque = new JButton("Braquer");
JButton TirHaut = new JButton("TirHaut");
JButton TirBas = new JButton("TirBas");
JButton TirDroite = new JButton("TirDroit");
JButton TirGauche = new JButton("TirGauche");

public VueBoutons() {


    this.add(Action);
    this.add(Avance);
    this.add(Recule);
    this.add(Monte);
    this.add(Descend);
    this.add(Braque);
    this.add(TirHaut);
    this.add(TirBas);
    this.add(TirDroite);
    this.add(TirGauche);

    disableboutAction(); // Au début on ne peut pas cliquer sur Action ! }

public void addActionListener(ActionListener e) {

    Action.setActionCommand("10");
    Action.addActionListener(e);

    Avance.setActionCommand("1");
    Avance.addActionListener(e);

    Recule.setActionCommand("2");
    Recule.addActionListener(e);

    Monte.setActionCommand("3");
    Monte.addActionListener(e);

    Descend.setActionCommand("4");
    Descend.addActionListener(e);

    Braque.setActionCommand("5");
    Braque.addActionListener(e);

    TirHaut.setActionCommand("6");
    TirHaut.addActionListener(e);

    TirBas.setActionCommand("7");
    TirBas.addActionListener(e);

    TirDroite.setActionCommand("8");
    TirDroite.addActionListener(e);

    TirGauche.setActionCommand("9");
    TirGauche.addActionListener(e);

}

public void disableActions() {
    Avance.setEnabled(false);
    Recule.setEnabled(false);
    Monte.setEnabled(false);
    Descend.setEnabled(false);
    TirHaut.setEnabled(false);
    TirBas.setEnabled(false);
    TirGauche.setEnabled(false);
    TirDroite.setEnabled(false);
    Braque.setEnabled(false);
}

public void disableboutAction() {
    Action.setEnabled(false);
}

public void enableActions() {
    Avance.setEnabled(true);
    Recule.setEnabled(true);
    Monte.setEnabled(true);
    Descend.setEnabled(true);
    TirHaut.setEnabled(true);
    TirBas.setEnabled(true);
    TirGauche.setEnabled(true);
    TirDroite.setEnabled(true);
    Braque.setEnabled(true);
}

public void enableboutAction() {
    Action.setEnabled(true);
}

public void disableTout() {
    Avance.setEnabled(false);
    Recule.setEnabled(false);
    Monte.setEnabled(false);
    Descend.setEnabled(false);
    TirHaut.setEnabled(false);
    TirBas.setEnabled(false);
    TirGauche.setEnabled(false);
    TirDroite.setEnabled(false);
    Braque.setEnabled(false);
    Action.setEnabled(false);
}}
```

Second class :

```
public class Controleur {

private int a;
private int numj;
private int numact;

private Modele modele;
private VueInterface vueI;

public Controleur(Modele modele, VueInterface vueI) {
    System.out.println("work");
    this.numj = 0;
    this.numact = 0;
    this.modele = modele;

    this.vueI = new VueInterface(modele);

    vueI.getCommandes().addActionListener(new CActionListener());
    // Instancie l'équivalent de la classe "Controleur" de Conway
    // de sorte à avoir une classe séparé et non pas interne
}

class CActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        a = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());
        System.out.println("It doesn't even work until here...............");

        if (modele.getPhaseP() && !modele.getPhaseA() && a <= Direction.values().length * 2) {
            // Cf classe Modele méthode uneAction() pour la condition

            modele.getListBandits().get(numj).ajouteAction(a);

            if (numact < modele.getNbactions())
                ++numact;

            else if (numj < modele.getNbjoueurs()) {
                numact = 0;
                ++numj;
            } else {
                numj = 0;
                numact = 0;
                System.out.println("******** Fin de la phase de planification ********");
                vueI.getCommandes().disableActions();
                vueI.getCommandes().enableboutAction();
                modele.setPhaseP(false);
                modele.setPhaseA(true);
            }
        } else if (modele.getPhaseA() && !modele.getPhaseP()) {

            if(a == 10) {
                modele.uneAction(numj, numact);

                if(numj < modele.getNbjoueurs()) // On fait toutes les 1res  actions de chaque joueurs etc
                    ++numj;
                else if (numact < modele.getNbactions()) {
                    numj = 0;
                    ++numact;
                } else {
                    modele.setPhaseP(false);
                    modele.setPhaseA(false);
                }

            }
        }

    }

}}
```

Last one partially concerned :

```
public class VueInterface extends JPanel {

private JFrame fenetre;
private JFrame actions;

private VueBoutons commandes;
private VueGrille grille;
private VueListeActions liactions;

public VueInterface(Modele modele) {

    this.fenetre = new JFrame("Colt Express");
    this.actions = new JFrame("Actions");

    this.commandes = new VueBoutons();
    this.grille = new VueGrille(modele);
    this.liactions = new VueListeActions(modele);

    fenetre.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel boutons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    boutons.add(commandes);

    fenetre.add(boutons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    fenetre.add(grille.getGrid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    actions.add(liactions.getPane());

    actions.pack();
    //fenetre.setResizable(false);
    fenetre.pack();
    fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}



public VueBoutons getCommandes() {
    return commandes;
}

public JFrame getActionFrame() {
    return actions;
}

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return fenetre;
}}
```

Thank you for your help !!

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you make use `Controleur` which would actually bind the `ActionListener` to the buttons

Comment: This line : vueI.getCommandes().addActionListener(new CActionListener()); (but I'm not sure to understand what you're saying, my native language isn't english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that in the constructor of your `Controleur` there are 2 `vueI`:

```
this.vueI = new VueInterface(modele);
vueI.getCommandes().addActionListener(new CActionListener());
```

These 2 lines affect different `VueInterface` instances.

Comment: You're write ! Forgot to change it, thank you ! I've another problem, i'll post here again instead of creating a new post. I've 2 classes Observable and Observers you probably know what it is if you have ever used MVC, but by calling my notifyobservers(); after an action nothing happens, my gridlayout doesn't change

Comment: If it was helpful and solved your problem, you should accept this answer.